# How does closure work for Ruby's define_singleton_method?

Tags: ruby, closures

This Ruby (2.2.3p173) code:

```
class A
    def msg
        "hello"
    end

    def p
        Proc.new { msg }
    end

    def lam
        lambda { msg }
    end

    def blk
        (1..3).map { msg }.join(" and ")
    end

    def d1(obj)
        obj.define_singleton_method(:say1) { msg }
    end

    def d2(obj)
        bound = msg # <== Why is this needed?
        obj.define_singleton_method(:say2) { bound }
    end
end

a = A.new

puts a.p.call

puts a.lam.call

puts a.blk

obj = Object.new

a.d1(obj)

begin
# Why does this fail?
puts obj.say1
rescue
puts "caught: #{$!}"
end

a.d2(obj)

puts obj.say2
```

produces this output:

```
hello
hello
hello and hello and hello
caught: undefined local variable or method `msg' for #<Object:0x00000001a20638>
hello
```

What makes the difference in d1 and d2? Why do all of the blocks see msg except for the one passed to define_singleton_method?

Update:

I think it comes down to this:

> Proc bodies have a lexical scope like functions in Lisp and
>   JavaScript, meaning that when Ruby encounters a free variable inside a
>   proc body, its value is resolved within the context the proc was
>   defined. This is what makes closures possible. Methods are different,
>   however. A method's context is the object to which they are bound.
>   When Ruby encounters a free variable inside a method body, it assumes
>   the variable refers to another method on the object, and this is what
>   saves us from having to prefix same-object methods with "this" or
>   "self".

which I found here: [Of closures, methods, procs, scope, and Ruby](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2006/12/of_closures_met_1.html).

All of these various blocks with `{ msg }` must work as Proc body does. `define_singleton_method` is taking the block and giving it method's rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer has to do with `self` and scopes

There are three ways to create a new scope in ruby.
Classes, Modules, and Methods.

Your class creates a scope, and each of your methods create a scope that contain bindings specific to them. Closures are special though. A closure will grab the bindings that are around when you define the block and the block specific bindings disappear after the block ends. For example:

```
def my_method
  #Method scope
  x = "Goodbye"
  yield("Cruel")
end

x = "Hello"
#Closure says "I am going to grab the local bindings from my scope
my_method {|y| "#{x}, #{y} world" }
```

When ever you write the code

```
obj.define_singleton_method(:say1) { msg }
```

The only local bindings the closure grabs is 'obj'
This can be demonstrated by modifying the code like so:

```
def d2(obj)
   puts "in the scope of method :d2, I have acces to the :msg method: #{methods.include?(:msg)}"
   puts "---"

    obj.define_singleton_method(:say2) do 
      puts "in the scope of this closure, I have acces to the :msg method: #{methods.include?(:msg)}"
      puts "Things I do have access to: "
      puts methods
      puts local_variables
    end
  end
```

A simple print statement of the most important part of ruby, self, will show you that you are operating in different scopes. Check out the code below:

```
def d2(obj)
   puts "in the scope of method :d2, I am operating as #{self}"
   puts "---"

    obj.define_singleton_method(:say2) do 
      puts "in the scope of this closure, I am operating as #{self}"
    end
end
```

So in short, the reason is because of scope. Whenever you declare `bound = msg` you are making the contents of `msg` local to the method and then the closure then can pick up the local binding value of `msg`.

If you want to read more about how this works, I highly recommend "The Pragmatic Programmers - Metaprogramming Ruby" You will learn a lot about self, and closures.
[http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Facets/dp/1941222129](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1941222129)

----EDIT----
"Why is"

`def p
   Proc.new { msg }
end`

different than

`def d2(obj)
  obj.define_singleton_method(:say2) { msg }
end`

It is different because self inside the block is different. Inside the method definition "p", the block has access to instance variables and methods, whereas the method "d2" has a block that only has access to Object. We can prove this with a little monkeypatching. Add this code:

`class Object
  def msg
     "GoodBye"
  end`

Comment: I understand that bound = msg creates a binding for the closure to see. But how is this different than Proc.new { msg }? How does this block { msg } see msg, but this block { msg } does not?

Comment: Ok  I am going to guess what the answer is: this block { msg } in the Proc, lambda, and block passed to map must resolve to self#msg with self set to the instance, where the self of the define_instance_method is obviously obj. I'll try your idea of puts self to examine this further. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have my answer. See my edit to my question.

Comment: You are correct. When you are creating the method that contains "Proc.new {msg}" self evaluates to the instance of the class, and because you defined "msg" as a public instance method, all instances have acces to them and therefore, because the proc is defined in the scope of the instance, it can access the method. When you write "obj." you are changing "self" to object and the "define.." method is sent to the object and the block is evaluated in the scope of the object

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!